# How s:bean tag works in struts 2?

Tags: java, struts2

Here's the example from the [bean tag docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/bean.html):

```
<s:bean name="org.apache.struts2.example.counter.SimpleCounter" var="counter">
  <s:param name="foo" value="BAR" />
  The value of foot is : <s:property value="foo"/>, when inside the bean tag <br />
</s:bean>
```

Then here is the explanation:

> This example instantiates a bean called `SimpleCounter` and sets the `foo` property (`setFoo('BAR')`). The `SimpleCounter` object is then pushed onto the value stack, which means that we can call its accessor methods (`getFoo()`) with the property tag and get their values.

In the above example, the id has been set to a value of counter. This means that the `SimpleCounter` class will be placed into the stack's context. You can access the `SimpleCounter` class using a Struts tag:

```
<s:property value="#counter" />
```

My question is if I mention attribute var in bean tag, will `SimpleCounter` be placed on value stack or stack's context? (I am taking stack context as action context right?)

If on value stack, then how come we are referring counter variable with `#` as `#` is used  to refer the value from action context instead of value stack. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong.

The "application context" is purely a servlet spec artifact and is not directly related to the OGNL `#` character. OGNL's `#` allows us to access named value stack values, as opposed to walking the value stack until an appropriate value is found.

It's also inaccurate to say "[...] the id has been set to a value of `counter`". `counter` is a named value in the value stack. I think of the value stack as a combination of context and stack--there's a stack, but there are also named values *not on the stack*, e.g., `#attr`.

I also don't think it's accurate to refer to it as the "action context", because that has a specific meaning in the context of a Struts 2 application, and is really only meaningful on the Java source side of things.

It's simple "the value stack", which includes a stack, and named values.

Comment: Hi Dave sorry i meant action context instead of application context. Corrected in my original post. You said "OGNL's # allows us to access named value stack values" If this is correct , i have also seen #session.user.name  where session does not lie in value stack but in action context. Also in #attr, attr lies on action context.As per above findings looks # is used to look in to action context and if we do not mention #, it will look in to value stack. Whole confusion is bcoz of word stack's context in statement "This means that the SimpleCounter class will be placed into the stack's context"

Comment: @MSach No, `#session` is a named value put into the value stack context. Where stack values *come from* isn't relevant. `#` is for referencing value stack context values, just like that sentence says--that is *not* the same as the action context. OGNL exists outside of Struts 2.